# Show that $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 , \, x<y\}$ is Borel

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

In my homework I want to show that $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 , \, x<y\}$ is Borel and determine if A is open or closed

My idea was to say that:

$A$ is the intersection or all $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1 $ but I don't know how to handle the x

Also it seems closed on the half-circle but open on the $x<y$ but it doesn't make sense that it is both open and closed.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ is a Borel set ($\because$ it is closed), $A_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x-y<0\}$ is a Borel set ($\because$ it is open). Then $A=A_1\cap A_2$ is also a Borel set.

Comment: I am assuming you argument that $A_1$ Borel because it is continuous. But why is $A_2$ Borel?

Comment: Any open or closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Borel set (by the definition of Borel $\sigma$-field).

Comment: Is $A=A_1 \cap A_2$ then an open or closed set? Because it is the intersection of an open and a closed set

Comment: It is neither open nor closed.